# Why don't metaballs show up in group instance?

Tags: particles, instances, meta-objects

I created a particle system, with metaballs as my object. I then added this particle system and a few other objects to a group. When I add a new instance of that group, the metaballs are not visible in the instance.

Does anyone know what is happening? Is there a way to make the metaballs visible in the group instance?

Comment: This is probably a bug. You can convert them to mesh as a workaround, but I guess that is not what you want.

Comment: Hi Duarte, does it work when you try it on your version of Blender? I've tried a few versions and the metaball cannot be instanced in any of them.

Comment: It does not work either, no further action should be required, hence why I think it is a bug. Bugs are considered off topic here though, and [should be reported to the developers instead](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/), so I'm closing this questionas such

Comment: Curiously it doesn't seem to work in 2.79 either, which makes it a very long standing bug that somehow slipped through

Comment: I noticed that too. And I unfortunately need to use 2.79 for this animation. Will make sure to report it though. Thanks for your help!